# Failed to install mysql2 while creating rails new app

Tags: mysql, makefile

While creating rails app using mysql as a database, I get the following error

```
...
...
Installing mysql2(0.3.13)
Gem:Installer::ExtensionBuilderError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd<>... yes
checking for rb_has_dup<>... yes
checking for rb_intern3<>... yes
***extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reasons, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log for more details. You may need configuration options
```

However, if I use default sqlite database, there is no problem

```
My OS & MySQL information
OS:Winodows 8 64bit
MySQL: 5.6(64 bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately mysql2 gem has issues,you'll have to install mysql gem for now,to do that do a bundle install after modifying to mysql from mysql2/sqlite in your config/database.yml and gemfile,hope thats clear.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that you make a lot of edits that remove tags. Try not to do that, because that makes a question harder to find. Instead, try to edit the question itself. Thanks!